# handling many similar div tags

Tags: html, css

I have many similar div tags in my page in this form

```
  <div class="singleline" style="width: 524px; height: 25px;">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
```

Now I want to use a css file to give different alignments to these
tags. I am not able to do this because everything in the tag is the same including
the content.

The additional limitation  is that I cannot change (or add) to the div tag
contents either.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Your question is confusing, If you want to apply multiple styles to the div tag you can have multiple classes just put a space in between them <div class="singleLine blue bolded"></div>

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Is there any pattern at all you can use to distinguish the divs you want to change? If not, there's no way you can give different styles without marking them as different from the start.

Comment: Do you mean you want to style these identical DIV elements individually without changing the markup?

Answer (score 0):

The best option I could see you using is CSS3 pseudo-selectors.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos

You'd be looking to use the :nth-child or nth-of-type() which would allow you to select individual div's in order on the page.

However, if the order of elements needed to change, or a new div is inserted above others, this would require a lot of reordering work in the CSS.

Your best option, if at all possible, is to give the div's individual unique IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is indeed confusing.I agree with SuperPaperSam but if the issue is that you cannot change your HTML I would suggest (if possible) using javascript to manipulate your DOM, to either directly edit the style of the divs or to add a class name or ID on them which will allow them to be styled by your CSS.